# vim displays rbg codes in quickfix bar before error output

Tags: linux, bash, vim, fish

Recently I've started using :make and various other commands that make use of the quickfix bar. However the output it produces has this initial line of an escape character and rgb codes.

[image: Example quickfix output]

I was able to remove this line previously setting the shell to bash instead of fish which is my default, but this don't work for plugins that make use of the bar (namely `fireplace.vim/dispatch.vim`). Any ideas for debugging this further or any man pages that may be relevant?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible debugging process:

- Go back to your default shell, fish. Might as well get this resolved in your regular environment
- Start vim with defaults, either:

  - For recent vim versions
    `vim --clean [files]`
  - For older vim versions
    `vim -u DEFAULTS -U NONE -i NONE [files]`
- then re-run
  `:make`

If the escape codes and rbg are gone, then add it issue is probably with your ***.vimrc*** or one or a combination of plugins.
Removing them all and adding them back one at a time and retesting with `:make` will narrow down what item is triggering the issue.